# Get content of RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

atm i have a problem with a recyclerview in my app.

The RecyclerView looks Like this

Categorie - All
Where - Place
When - Now
Who - Anyone

If you click on a row, you can define the items.
For example

Categorie - Football
Where - Everywhere
When - Tomorrow
Who Anyone

When the user klicks now on a button under the reyclerview, i want to send the choosen data to my server, but i cant get the information out of the Recyclerview.

If i use

```
recyclerview.getChildAt(0).toString();
```

it just gave me a RelativeLayout back.

Someone has a idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: recyclerView.getChildAt(0) will give you the view @ 0th index. How you are adding data to recyclerView child views..? Is there any list or array which has your data(i.e., Category, Place etc..)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a child of the RecyclerView, which is a RelativeLayout. This RelativeLayout contains the EditText (or TextView) you want to read.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) recyclerview.getChildAt(0);
EditText editText = (EditText) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
String info = editText.getText();
```

Comment: damn havent though this solution, but it works perfect ! thx mate

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a list to set the data in the recyclerView, simply get the data from that list. Like

```
list.get(position)
```

where position is the position of clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

you should customize a item listener in your adapter.

first, implements View.OnClickListener with ViewHolder

like this:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (onItemClickListener != null) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
 }
```

after that, in adapter customize a listener and setListener:

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {

    this.onItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    boolean onItemLongClick(View view,int position);
}
```

in the end , you can according to the position of interface to return back to obtain the corresponding data

hope i can help you !